# Filter options material-ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJs, Material-UI autocomplete with **20000 options** for select. Each option represented as object with portfolio, country and assetType.

```
 const options = [{portfolio: 'test_index', country: 'Austria', assetType: 'index'},
 { portfolio: 'Italy $1M Turnover StdTurn btm 10 Middle of Quarter LCL', country: 'Italy', assetType: 'portfolio'},
 { portfolio: 'Israel $1M Turnover StdTurn top 20 Middle of Quarter LCL', country: 'Italy', assetType: 'portfolio'},
 { portfolio: 'United States $1M Turnover ROE top 20 Middle of Quarter LCL', country: 'Italy', assetType: 'portfolio'}]
```

I need to filter options by '**portfolio**'. Filter should work like contain.
Such that if type *Italy Middle* or *Middle Italy* i get this responce 'Italy $1M Turnover StdTurn btm 10 Middle of Quarter LCL'

Material-ui recommend several options : createFilterOptions and [match-sorter](https://github.com/kentcdodds/match-sorter)

- match-sorter work very slow with a huge amount of data. Also if you change order of the words like *Middle Italy* search does not work.
- createFilterOptions does not work like contain.
  Autocomplete looks like following:

```html
    <Autocomplete
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      size="small"
      id="assets_async_autocmplete"
      className={classes.root}
      disableListWrap
      sx={{ width: 365 }}
      open={open}
      PopperComponent={StyledPopper}
      ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
      onOpen={() => {
        setOpen(true);
      }}
      onClose={() => {
        setOpen(false);
      }}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option === value}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.portfolio}
      options={options}
      loading={loading}
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <Stack
          key={option.portfolio}
          justifyContent="center"
        >
          <SearchRowContainer saveAssetId={saveAssetId} props={props} favorites={favorites} option={option} />
          <hr className={style.delimeter} />
        </Stack>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <RenderInput params={params} loading={loading} />
      )}
      popupIcon={<GlassIcon />}
    />
```

Can anybody suggest efficient way\library to filter the options.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably have the matching done by the backend like with full text search by postgres, or algolia, elastic search of something if that's possible. But if you really want to load the full list, have a look at the virtualisation option Mui5 added https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#virtualization too. and for the filtering https://fusejs.io/examples.html#search-string-array could be an option too.